# Firebase Phone Number Authentication Issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase in my project for phone number verification.
 A few phone numbers have this issue. Alert like

> "There seems to be a problem with your project's  firebase phone number authentication set-up, please make sure to follow the instructions found at https:// firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth"

Any idea where to look next? Thanks in advance.

[**Alert Msg Screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTMwN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You get this message if the user has disabled notifications.

> To use phone number authentication, your app must be able to receive
>   silent APNs notifications from Firebase.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth